# Android - looking for old certificate for debug

Tags: android, google-play, certificate

I want to re-post changed old app to Google Play with same signature to allow for update from old version. I've found it was signed with `Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US, Valid from: MSK 2013`  so maybe somebody can give me old `debug.keystore` file (my Studio 1.5 has other certificate fingerprints). It's a shot in the sky, but maybe...

I've read somewhere Google Play does not allow to post app signed with debug, however AFAIK the old app was on Google Play.

P.S. I just do not get it - I just saw I signed app with certificate that is valid till 2013 and it was installed today on phone with current date AFAIK. Are certificates for Google Play only?

See full cert info below:

Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 5263616f
Valid from: Sun Oct 20 08:51:59 MSK 2013 until: Tue Oct 13 07:51:59 MSK 2043
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  EF:11:27:9D:85:90:1E:EE:84:2A:DD:F5:5C:CB:F8:C0
         SHA1: 64:33:5B:9F:BA:7F:FA:21:5D:89:9B:F8:3C:87:05:71:E7:F1:98:7B
         SHA256: 84:A1:94:DA:4D:23:EC:59:7D:20:77:BD:2B:AE:DE:7B:C2:1C:DE:92:4E:
51:19:D2:63:73:1E:FF:0C:D7:E4:1C
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3

Comment: If I can give it to you,your app is mine.

Comment: @tiny sunlight, is it an offer or humor? the file I assume is standard from old Android Studio or Eclipse. The password should be "android" etc.

Answer (score 0):

`debug.keystore` file is not standard, it's generated by each Android Studio installation as I've found out. So my search is not relevant.